# Preventing the JVM from writing to System.out or reading from System.in

Tags: java, security, io, permissions, jvm

Is there a way under the JVM to (temporarily) prevent complete access to System.out, System.in and System.err ?

After creating a blank policy which grants no permission at all, I want to execute some work in the function below. **I would like calls to System.out.println and the like to fail, but they don't.** Is there something I can do or am I being a little too much of a control freak ?

**EDIT #1:** Following MrPixelDream's suggestion to use `System.setOut`, I am keeping the permissions to a minimum to make sure code within `run()` cannot also call `System.setOut` or fool around with `java.io.FileDescriptor.out`.

**EDIT #2:** Also, since rogue code could have simply executed `standardOutput.println`, I prefered not to keep a reference to `System.out` around at all and set it back using `java.io.FileDescriptor.out`.

```
// Create blank permissions that barely allow executing code
java.security.Permissions perm = new java.security.Permissions();

// CodeSource domain for which these permissions apply (all files)
java.security.CodeSource code = new java.security.CodeSource(new java.net.URL("file:/*"),
                                                             null);

// ProtectionDomain
java.security.ProtectionDomain domain = new java.security.ProtectionDomain(code, perm);

// AccessControlContext
java.security.ProtectionDomain[] domains = new java.security.ProtectionDomain[1];
domains[0] = domain;

java.security.AccessControlContext context =
  new java.security.AccessControlContext(domains);

// DON'T keep reference to standard output, it could be used directly
// PrintStream standardOut = System.out;

// Redirect output to dummy stream
System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]));
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream()));
System.setErr(new PrintStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream()));

// Do an action, subject to the given security context
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {

  public Void run() {

    // Do some work, side effects and all, but no I/O whatsoever
    System.out.println("Will not print !");

    // Try to fool around System.out with direct access from file descriptors (0, 1, 2)
    java.io.PrintStream myOut =
      new java.io.PrintStream(new java.io.FileOutputStream(java.io.FileDescriptor.out));

    // Missing permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "setIO"
    // Will throw java.security.AccessControlException
    System.setOut(myOut);

    // Missing permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "writeFileDescriptor"
    myOut.println("Will throw java.security.AccessControlException !");

  }

}, context);

// Now set back the old streams to have output again
System.setIn(new java.io.FileInputStream(java.io.FileDescriptor.in));
System.setOut(
  new java.io.PrintStream(new java.io.FileOutputStream(java.io.FileDescriptor.out)));
System.setErr(
  new java.io.PrintStream(new java.io.FileOutputStream(java.io.FileDescriptor.err)));
```

Comment: "Am I being too much of a control freak?" Maybe, why do you want to prevent it?

Comment: Long story short, I am using System.in/System.out to communicate between this restricted child JVM and its parent JVM. The child JVM submits user provided javascript code to Nashorn and returns the result to the parent JVM through System.out. If the javascript code were to print as well, it would potentially mess my communication channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer of Elliott Frisch will do the trick, but you cant receive output after doing it. If you intend to have output muted just temporarily, use this code:

```
public class RedirectedOutput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Save the old output stream to have the chance to set it back later
        InputStream standardIn  = System.in;
        PrintStream standardOut = System.out;
        PrintStream standardErr = System.err;

        // Set useless streams
        System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]));
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream()));
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream()));

        // Will not be shown
        System.out.println("Hello World");

        // Now set back the old streams to have output again
        System.setIn(standardIn);
        System.setOut(standardOut);
        System.setErr(standardErr);

        // Will be shown again
        System.out.println("Finally we got the Hello");
    }

}
```

You can try out this example which should be fully runnable. It should be self-explaining. You are using `setIn()`, `setOut()` and `setErr()` to change the streams and you save it before to be able to set it back.

But if you don't need **any** output, you are better with Elliott's code because I guess it's better for resources.

Comment: Since Elliot's answer I came out with something similar but I was setting System.out to null which required me to catch exceptions. Your solution, by providing a temporary dummy stream, avoids failure of the executed code and is satisfactory. Of course, as far as resources are concerned, nothing prevents the executed code to bloat the heap in various ways.

Comment: Thank you for summing up your thoughts and of course for accepting my answer. Glad to help.

Comment: As a note, your code will do but would fail to contain rogue code without a proper policy. I have updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is a way to do this temporarily, but you can prevent them writing or reading until the JVM is restarted by `close()`ing them with something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.err.close();
    System.out.close();
    System.out.println("Must not print !");
}
```

And there is **no** output.